# When I Try to use same instance of Datamanger in D3 js, the Axis is incorrect

Tags: asp.net, d3.js

I am new to D3 js, I've used same instance of data manager to load json files which retrieved data from the two entirely different table.

But because of this, the axis does not display properly.

If i try to use different instance of DataManager to load the two different JSON files
respectively, the axis displays properly. The problem is, If i use two different datamanger instance the events declared in the one datamanager "onReady" event can't be usedin the other instance of datamanager.

Any Help is appreciated !

Comment: What is DataManager? A Windows server module?

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: datamanger is where we prepare our data before display. d3.op ={} d3.op.datamanager = function module(){} and we will create the instance ie instance = d3.op.datamanger(); and use this instance to load the json using loadjson funciton ie instance.loadJson().